# Is it possible to write an IM server in python? (be able to handle the heavy connections)

Tags: python, instant-messaging

i wanna write an IM server in python, but i'm not sure if python can handle the heavy connections?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's a question of programmer skill, not python's "ability". Python can handle it, no sweat.

Answer (score 2):

[Omegle](http://omegle.com/) is written in Python and as of writing is sustaining 7,057 concurrent online users.

It's not so much about the choice of language, but the efficiency of your code and how well it is optimized.

```
while true:
    # nothing
```

isn't going to be any slower than

```
while (1) ;
```

Comment: Omegle uses Twisted (http://twistedmatrix.com/), a highly scalable Python networking library.

Comment: i used Omegle once and i didn't know it is written in Python but even the server side? Because i think it uses python web framework only(i just guessing). Thanks anyway =]

Comment: Omegle originally used Twisted but was rewritten to use gevent (gevent.org): http://groups.google.com/group/gevent/msg/d15a840088291f61

Comment: @kyle. you are correct. omegle only uses python client side in the browser

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you could :)

For example: SecondLife has written a library to support non-blocking IO, you can find it at: http://eventlet.net/

The beauty of Python is, you can optimize the code when it's needed. If some part of your code is executed a lot you can simply replace it with a C function to speed up your entire program without much effort.

Comment: Thankssssss a lot. This library is so awesome.

Answer (score 1):

[gevent](http://www.gevent.org) is a Python network library based on libevent that is capable of handling thousands of connections. Read the [introduction here](http://www.gevent.org/intro.html).